# Win32 CryptProtectData how to save output data?

Tags: c++, winapi, unreal-engine4

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dpapi/nf-dpapi-cryptprotectdata

How can I save the output key to the windows registry or a file? I've been trying to do this for two days now but no progress. One of the problems is that I am using Unreal Engine and they have their own string type "FString" which does not easily convert to std::string or const char*

This is the code I'm using to save to the registry, but I'm not sure if it's valid:

```
void SUGH1LoginWidget::SecureSaveJWTToken(FString JWT_Token)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    DATA_BLOB DataIn;
    DATA_BLOB DataOut; // Key to decrypt the data. Store in windows registry. 
    DATA_BLOB EncryptionKey; // Uses define in ShooterGame.h to encrypt the data so that only the UGH1 application can access the token. 
    DWORD cbDataInput = lstrlenA((char*)TCHAR_TO_ANSI(*JWT_Token)) + 1;
    DataIn.pbData = (BYTE*)ConvertFStringToCString(JWT_Token).get();
    DataIn.cbData = cbDataInput;

    BYTE* pbDataEncryptionKey = (BYTE*)TOKEN_ENCRYPTION_KEY;
    DWORD cbDataEncryptionKey = strlen((char*)pbDataEncryptionKey) + 1;
    EncryptionKey.pbData = pbDataEncryptionKey;
    EncryptionKey.cbData = cbDataEncryptionKey;

    // Finally save the data
    CryptProtectData(&DataIn, NULL, &EncryptionKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, &DataOut);
    SaveJWTDecryptionKeyToRegistry(DataOut);
#endif
}


void SUGH1LoginWidget::SaveJWTDecryptionKeyToRegistry(DATA_BLOB DecryptionKey)
{
    FString Base64EncryptionKey = FBase64::Encode(DecryptionKey.pbData, DecryptionKey.cbData);

    HKEY CurrentUserKey;
    LSTATUS Error;
    Error = RegOpenCurrentUser(KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &CurrentUserKey);
    if (Error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        HKEY SoftwareKey;
        Error = RegOpenKeyExA(CurrentUserKey, "SOFTWARE", NULL, KEY_WRITE, &SoftwareKey);
        if (Error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            HKEY UGHStudiosSubKey;
            Error = RegCreateKeyExA(SoftwareKey, "UGH Studios LLC", NULL, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_WRITE, NULL, &UGHStudiosSubKey, NULL);
            if (Error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                Error = RegSetValueExA(UGHStudiosSubKey, "LoginTokenDecryptionKey", NULL, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)TCHAR_TO_ANSI(*Base64EncryptionKey), Base64EncryptionKey.Len());
                RegCloseKey(UGHStudiosSubKey);
                RegCloseKey(SoftwareKey);
                if (Error != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    UE_LOG(LogLoginWidget, Error, TEXT("The game was unable to save the login token to the registry."));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        UE_LOG(LogLoginWidget, Error, TEXT("The game was unable to access the windows registry on this machine. "));
    }
    
    RegCloseKey(CurrentUserKey);
}
```

This is my code for loading from the registry back into an FString but it's not working properly:

```
std::shared_ptr<char[]> SUGH1LoginWidget::ConvertFStringToCString(const FString InputString)
{
    std::shared_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[InputString.Len()]);
    TArray<TCHAR> CharArray = InputString.GetCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < InputString.Len(); i++)
    {
        ptr[i] = CharArray[i];
    }
    return ptr;
}

PRAGMA_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION
FReply SUGH1LoginWidget::GetJWTTokenFromRegistry()
{
    TArray<uint8> DecryptionKeyBytes;
    // load base64 string from registry
    LSTATUS Error;
    HKEY UGHStudiosSubKey;
    Error = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "SOFTWARE\\UGH Studios LLC", NULL, KEY_READ, &UGHStudiosSubKey);
    if (Error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        char buffer[8193] = { 0 };
        DWORD dwLen = 8192;
        DWORD dwType = 0;
        Error = RegQueryValueExA(UGHStudiosSubKey, "LoginTokenDecryptionKey", 0, &dwType, (BYTE*)buffer, &dwLen);
        if (Error == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            std::string outValue = buffer;
            FString decoded_string;
            //FString reg_value_as_fstring = FString(outValue.length(), outValue.c_str());
            uint8* decoded = malloc();
            FBase64::Decode(outValue.c_str(), outValue.size(), decoded);

            //:Decode(const FString & Source, TArray<uint8>&OutDest
            //::Decode(const CharType* Source, uint32 Length, uint8* Dest)
            //UE_LOG(LogLoginWidget, Error, TEXT("Out value: %s"), *decoded_string);
        }
        //Error = RegQueryValueExA(UGHStudiosSubKey, "LoginTokenDecryptionKey", NULL, NULL, buffer, size);
        
        
        

        return FReply::Handled();
        //return decoded_string;
        //std::string outvalue = (char*)buffer;
        

    }

    //FBase64::Decode(, DecryptionKeyBytes)
    //return FString("");
    return FReply::Handled();
}
PRAGMA_ENABLE_OPTIMIZATION
```

What's the standard way of saving the struct data? I was tying to Base64 encrypt it and save it as a registry key. But this doesn't work.

Comment: Why bother at all with strings?  Just save the binary data as `REG_BINARY`.

Comment: Can I store the entire DATA_BLOB struct in just a single binary reg value?

Comment: I don't see why not.  `REG_BINARY` takes a pointer to any arbitrary data and the length of that data, and your `DATA_BLOB` contains both of those.  Passing `&blob` would be incorrect, of course.

Comment: Error = RegQueryValueExA(UGHStudiosSubKey, "LoginTokenDecryptionKey", NULL, NULL, blob.pbData, blob.cbData); <- This does not work from. cbData is supposed to be the size and pbData is the buffer itself. Any ideas? I tried casting cbData to DWORD but that didn't work either (obviously, it said it was an invalid param)

Comment: The last parameter of `RegQueryValueExA` is `LPDWORD`, a pointer to `DWORD`. You should pass an address of a variable that contains the size of the buffer on input, and is set to the number of bytes actually written upon return. You must already know this - you are passing `&dwLen` in one of your `RegQueryValueExA` calls.

Comment: Yes, don't just throw casts at stuff when you get a compiler error - take a moment to think things through.

Comment: I was able to get it to work! I got the entire setup that I was trying to make to work last night. I have it requesting a json web token from my python web service, which then the C++ application stores the jwt using the CryptProtect function, and then takes the key from that and stores the key in a binary registry key value and on decryption it grabs the key from the registry and decrypts and tries to login using my /verify_jwt_token endpoint! Wohoo